# Is a survey possible on meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to do survey on meta? I would like to hold a survey of what kind of aviation experience each member have.

Maybe a list will be

- GA pilot
- private or BizJet pilot
- airliner pilot
- atc
- flight attendant
  etc.

The purpose of the survey is that so we can expect what expertise is available here so we can ask appropiate question and expect answer here. Example, the question regards [IFE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/what-is-the-source-for-the-flight-data-shown-on-in-flight-entertainment-systems/11457#11457) seems quiet. Maybe the reason is lack of expertise? Any thought from you guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [brought up before](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/what-is-your-aviation-experience), although with different intentions. I honestly don't think a survey would help. There wouldn't be a great way to expose that information to users who come here the first time, and anyone who's been around for a while has a feel for what types of questions get good answers. Also, a more accurate way to explore the scope of the site is to simply ask questions and see what kinds of answers it gets. The ability to get people to participate in the survey also greatly hurts its chances at being valuable. Most people would miss it, so any specialized knowledge that one or two users have is likely to be sampled out from the start. It's also hard to quantify likelihood to answer questions on a topic, even if you know they have the knowledge.

If there was going to be a survey, Stack Exchange itself would probably need to be involved in order to be effective. I could ask our community team if that's something we ever do for the smaller sites (I know there's a survey for SO users once a year), and whether or not they think it would be a good idea in this case. However, my guess is that their answer will be the same as mine - that asking questions is far more effective at defining scope.

Comment: I didnt realise it's been brough up before. It is best to just ask away but it does not comfort me seeing valid question with no answer. Trying to figure how to improve this situation :)

Comment: @vasin1987 one solution is to share questions out on social media, to your friends, etc, if you think they're not reaching people with the right expertise.

Comment: I agree with @egid. If the question is out of scope it should be closed or migrated. If you think it should be in scope, then the ideal solution is to try to attract attention to that question, possibly outside the site itself. Out of 2006 questions asked, 54 have zero answers. That's 2.7% - pretty much on par with most successful Stack Exchange sites. There's always going to be some unanswered, or poorly answered questions, and there's nothing wrong with trying to improve upon that, but when put in perspective, it's not a particularly large problem for this site.

Comment: @vasin1987 just as a follow up, I did speak with our VP of Community Growth about this today, and he basically listed all of the reasons I gave you, and more, about why we'd be unlikely to learn anything from a survey of this sort. It's not that SE is against it, and as he put it, we're generally open to ideas from the community on ways to help sites, but a survey on meta is probably the wrong place to start in this case.